# several steps must be carried out

Tags: word-usage

Can I use carry out in this context:

> The app uses the Google maps Android API v2. To edit the application in Eclipse, several steps must be **carried out**:

Comment: The word "Steps" collocates with "take". Steps must be taken.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom - That's bad advice. Steps _can_ be carried out. [Have a look](https://www.google.com/search?q="carry+out+these+steps").

Comment: @J.R. I didn't suggest that he can't use it. It is just less common to use carry out steps than take steps, Ngram would agree with that. Also I said that the word steps collocates with steps, which means they are often used together.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom - One (particularly a learner) could easily misinterpret the word "must" in your "Steps must be taken" comment. (It's hard to tell if you're merely suggesting an alternate wording to the O.P.'s text, or declaring that _taken_ "must" be used in lieu of _carried out_.) Given the clarifications you made in your second comment, I wouldn't say your first comment is "bad advice," just "potentially misleading."

Comment: I think that "take steps" has a kind of idiomatic forcefulness that makes it mean something other than just "do these things."  For example, someone might say, "I will take steps to ensure my safety" where they would never say "I will carry out steps to ensure my safety", because "take steps" means something like "take the necessary actions".  if you are referring to particular steps, as in instructions, then I think *carry out* is fine.

Answer (score 1):

*carry out*, in this case, stands for *performing a task.* (*steps* can actually be performed.)

In this case you can say *several steps must be performed,* and *carried out* works as said.

Comment: I agree that _carried out_ works. That said, after reading your answer, I think _performed_ might be a better way to say it.

Comment: @J.R. Yes. I'd use *performed* as well but I think the OP wanted to use the phrasal verb.